# MYSQL Insert the same values in different table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with my script...

If I run this script, the value 'id' and 'name' will insert just in the first table "TABLE1", why this problem? the php doesn't get any error

```
<?php    
$id= $_GET['id'];
$name= $_GET['name'];

if(empty($id) || empty($name)){
        echo "errore";
}else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE1` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('','$id','$name','','','','')";
        mysql_query($sql);       

        $sql1="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE2` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('','$id','$name','','','','')";
        mysql_query($sql1);

        $sql2="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE3` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('','$id','$name','','','','')";
        mysql_query($sql2);                               
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

SCRIPT ONLINE:

```
<?php
require 'client/database.php';

$uid= mysql_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
$username= mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$email= mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']);

$con = mysql_connect($host, $dbu, $dbp);
if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

mysql_select_db($db, $con);
//end opening connection

if(empty($uid) || empty($username)){
        echo "errore";
}else{
//artist info
        $sql="INSERT INTO TABLE1 (UIDfacebook, username, email)
        VALUES
        ('$uid','$username','$email')";
        mysql_query($sql);       

        $sql1="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (UIDfacebook, username)
        VALUES
        ('$uid','$username')";
        mysql_query($sql1);


        $sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE3 (UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysql_query($sql2);


        $sql3="INSERT INTO TABLE4 (UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysql_query($sql3);

        $sql4="INSERT INTO TABLE5 (UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysql_query($sql4);

        echo "GOOD...";

}
//close connection
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

somebody know why? i try a lot of method without success...

thank you very much!!!

Comment: you are passing value to fields `(id, name)` only

Comment: mysql_*() don't "give" errors. They return a boolean false on error, which you're not checking for. **NEVER** assume success when dealing with external resources (e.g. a db). always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: you should switch to PDO or mysqlli, mysql_ is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're telling MySQL to update two columns and then giving it seven values. If you checked for errors using `mysql_error()` you would have caught this.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE1` (id, name)
    VALUES
    ('$id','$name')";
    mysql_query($sql);     
    if (mysql_error()) {
         echo mysql_error();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the number of columns must fit with the number of values. Change your code to the code bellow:

```
<?php    
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$name= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);

if(empty($id) || empty($name)){
        echo "errore";
}else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE1` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('$id','$name')";
        mysql_query($sql);       

        $sql1="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE2` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('$id','$name')";
        mysql_query($sql1);

        $sql2="INSERT INTO `$db`.`TABLE3` (id, name)
        VALUES
        ('$id','$name')";
        mysql_query($sql2);                               
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Be careful because somebody can inject mal-code in your table. try to validate $id and $name first

Comment: -1 This is an identical resolution as John's answer without any explanation

Comment: the best advise is my comment

Comment: The best advice is to drop deprecated `mysql_*` functions, however, if you think your comment is your best advice than I would recommend adding it to the answer rather than adding as a comment.

Comment: let say somebody add $id = '; delete from user;'

Comment: I am not going to debate something that doesn't relate to the OP's question.

Comment: thank you all, the last question is, how i can protect the code? i neet to insert the _GET inside of the value??

Comment: should note my response better than it is.

Comment: I have another problem, I fixed the script and is working in localhost, but when I try online, the script doesn't working, the script will insert the value just on the first table, and the php doesn't open any error!! I don't understand why :( I will add the code